# ASP.NET RC2 failing to restore packages

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

I installed RC2 update in my Visual Studio today and created a new ASP.NET project using .Net Core.

It creates the project but fails to restore packages. Did anyone else have this issue? What's the solution?

Comment: Which packages - NuGet, Node, Bower?

Comment: Were there any error messages about NUGET problems or you just observe that no restore of the packages has been done?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update to the [latest NuGet](https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.5.0-beta/NuGet.Tools.vsix) version (v3.5.0-beta).
If you have any custom NuGet feed configured in your NuGet.config file, try to temporary disable them or reorder them.

Last but not least, try it with the cli by running "dotnet restore" in your solution/project's folder.